# 1918 Bureau of Transportation Statistics North American Transportation Atlas Data?

Tags: geospatial, usa, historical, transportation, public-transport

In 2008 [User:NE2](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:NE2) on wikipedia added a bunch of train routes from 1918 to wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missouri%E2%80%93Kansas%E2%80%93Texas_Railroad#/media/File:Missouri,_Kansas_and_Texas_Railway_system_map_(1918).svg
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Detroit,_Toledo_and_Ironton_Railroad_system_map_(1918).svg
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Oregon_and_California_Railroad_system_map_(1918).svg
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Michigan_Central_Railroad_system_map_(1918).svg

He says the data for these maps came from "Bureau of Transportation Statistics North American Transportation Atlas Data". Google'ing that I found this:

https://data-usdot.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/north-american-rail-lines

But that data isn't from 1918.

Archives going as far back as 2011 can be found here:

https://www.bts.gov/archive/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/index

But 2011 is a far cry from 1918.

https://geodata.lib.ncsu.edu/fedgov/bts/nortad/ has data going back to 1998 but that's still not 1918.

So my question is...  where can I get train route info going back to 1918?